# git undo only changes to some files in a commit

Tags: git

What are best practices to accomplish this task:

I have commits:

```
A -- B -- C
```

Commit B consist of:

```
file1.java
file2.java
icon.png
```

I would like to undo changes to `file1` and `file2` but not to `icon.png`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stage a revert of commit B and then reset the image file before committing.

```
# Prepare a revert of B
git revert -n B

# Recover the current version of the image
git checkout HEAD -- icon.png

# Commit the "almost" reversion of B
git commit
```

Comment: Forgot that revert -n adds the files.